# LF an Analog SFF short story, Future medic/vet comes back to contemporary America and offers medical help to a disabled woman's father

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, animals

Looking for this for a blind friend of mine who's a bit cat-obsessed. He remembers listening to these on the national library service for the blind version of Analog some time in the 80s or 90s. I've done some keyword searches elsewhere without any luck.

If you have follow up questions I'll have to relay them to the person in question, which may take a day or so.

Synopsis: A vet from the future's ship malfunctions and is sent back to contemporary America. She lands near a farm, where the farmer has a mentally challenged daughter who also has a mentally challenged cat. She offers to help, but the father rebuffs her. As she's leaving, she cures the cat. He mentioned that he remembers the line about the cat 'staring at him with blazing intelligence' as he realizes his mistake.

Bullet points

- Also cat story
- Future vet, maybe alien vet
- Goes back in time or visits earth from more advanced culture
- Lands near farm
- Father has daughter who is mentally handicapped.
- Daughter has cat who is likewise handicapped.
- Vet offers to fix the daughter.
- Father says no
- Vet fixes the cat on her way out.

Comment: @user14111 - I think it's pretty clear that it's veterinarian. Fixing cats is kinda their thing

Comment: @user14111 - Because vet(erinarian)s can treat human illnesses too.

Comment: @user14111 The title says "medic/vet" which is why he wants to fix the daughter too.

Comment: @user14111 yes, entirely possible it's in another magazines